# High res Laser Printer for home use

Tags: color, dpi, laser

Im looking for a 2400 x 2400 DPI Color Laser Printer, I can't seem to find anything cheaper than the Xerox D560, but I want to use it at home... Is there anything like that?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Just wanna point out that im not looking for a CHEAP quality laser printer... I'm researching on the web, and I can't find anything a little bit smaller than a Xerox D560 :/ The technology doesn't make it possible to be a little bit less expensive/smaller? Or I'm just not looking on the right places? Thanks once more, it's a legit question, I appreciate if you don't just close it.

Comment: Good question in my opinion. Not sure why someone voted to close it and downvote it.

Comment: @Ryan presumably because it has no future, much like asking for hardware for a design computer. Anyway color lasers like this aren't exactly bulk products

Comment: Tehcnolgical possibility is not usually a limitting factor in product design. In this case i suspect simple segmentation of the product range is enough.  See you want a very top of the line feature, many times the other segments get worse quality just because its business imperative. But yes a 2400dpi tractor is a bit tricky.

Comment: Highest resolution I could find for home Laser printers was the Lexmark CS410dtn: 1200x1200 (BW) + 2400x600(c). All the others I saw are 2400x600. Doesn't seem to be anything higher resolution as of jun-2016.

Comment: Well, there seems to be technologies that improve image quality not by just aumenting dpi. Like 4 bit dots. Why is the requirement of 2400 for a home user printer?

Comment: If OKI Data has a printer that fits your resolution requirements, I would highly recommend the brand. In 15 years we are on our 2nd one...the one we have now is the OKI Data MPS 9650, we've had it for about 5-6 years, with no service calls. Great color, great durability. We run cardstock through it 75% of the time, so it takes a beating. The consumables are all user-changeable and super easy to change, including the transfer belt and fuser unit.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the price you have been quoted or whether A4 will do but I would recommend Oki data units. The Oki C610n Colour A4 is 2440 dpi and I have seen it quoted online for £230. The 'n' is for network / ethernet built in which I would recommend if you are shipping lots of data. I have been running the same Oki B4350n unit for 10+ years now in a graphic design office with no issue at all - my model is 1220 dpi B/White and postscript - works great from Adobe and Apple apps including postscript. I use it for pre-proofing brochure copy mostly and it can get quite heavy regular use.  I found out about Oki from a Pro / trade source originally - you don't find them in high street stores. Any decent printer tech will know about them though. Never had an issue with parts or supplies. Pretty tough and rugged.